How do I get the unique ID of an NFC tag, developing with .net maui for IOS?
I'm developing an app with maui that interacts with NFC tags, I've already done the part to start the session and get the Tag object.
Now how do I get the unique ID from my Tag object ?
Thank you
I searched a bit on the web, but I only found examples with .swift, and not with maui.

Please post the relevant code that shows how you are retrieving the Tag
